# BeagleBoneBlack Analog Input Files Does not Exist

Tags: debian, beagleboneblack, analog-digital-converter

I want to make a simple project using BBB.I am following these steps from [Web Site](http://embedded-basics.blogspot.com.tr/2014/10/beaglebone-black-analog-input-pins.html) but there is no "AIN1" file on my BBB [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5Ucc.jpg)  and i don't understand where is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are two modes of ADC in BBB, For single shot mode just cat to the address

> cat /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/in_voltage4_raw

If you want in continuous mode do the following and it should get you started properly.

Consider you want to start ADC 1, 5, then

> echo 1 >
> /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/scan_elements/in_voltage0_en
>
> echo 1 > /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/scan_elements/in_voltage5_en

in terminal and then set buffer length by

> echo 100 > /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/buffer/length

then start ADC

> echo 1 > /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/buffer/enable